Adding items to list app with the enter key has made other features not work properly
List app works great until I add a keydown for the enter key. I can only get it to work if it's outside of the newItem() function. When I have the keydown function inside of newItem() function, the input field just clears and I don't get any errors, but nothing submits.
My problem is when I put the keydown function outside of newItem() function, the crossOutButton(), strike css feature, and sortable() don't work because they're now outside of the scope. I'm guessing there is a solution to where it can all go inside the newItem() function, but I'm stuck.


function newItem() {

  //Adds new item to the list
  let li = $('<li></li>');
  let inputValue = $('#input').val();
  li.append(inputValue);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert('You must write something');
  } else {
    $('#list').append(li);
    //clears input field after selecting 'Add' button
    $('#input').val('');
  }

  //Crossing out an item from the list of items
  function crossOut() {
    li.toggleClass('strike');
  }

  li.on('dblclick', function crossOut() {
    li.toggleClass('strike');
  });

  //Adding the delete button 'X'
  let crossOutButton = $('<crossOutButton></crossOutButton>');
  crossOutButton.append(document.createTextNode('X'));
  li.append(crossOutButton);

  crossOutButton.on('click', deleteListItem);
  //Adding class delete (display: none) from css
  function deleteListItem() {
    li.addClass('delete');
  }

  //reordering the items
  $('#list').sortable();

}

//keydown function to listen for enter key
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').keydown(function(e) {

    //initialized variable and set as undefined
    let inputValue;

    if (inputValue === '') {
      alert("You must enter something");
    } else {
      //Enter key holds the value of 13
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        let li = `<li>${$(this).val()}</li>`;
        $('#list').append(li);
        console.log('Form submitted');

        e.preventDefault();
        //clears input field after hitting enter
        $('#input').val('');
      }
    }
  })
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" name="listItem" id="input">
</form>

<div onclick="newItem()" id="button">Add</div>
<br/>
<ol id="list"></ol>




The proper way to capture the enter key (and indeed to capture the button click) - is to capture the submit event of the form (and cancel it).


function newItem() {

  //Adds new item to the list
  let li = $('<li></li>');
  let inputValue = $('#input').val();
  li.append(inputValue);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert('You must write something');
  } else {
    $('#list').append(li);
    //clears input field after selecting 'Add' button
    $('#input').val('');
  }

  //Crossing out an item from the list of items
  function crossOut() {
    li.toggleClass('strike');
  }

  li.on('dblclick', function crossOut() {
    li.toggleClass('strike');
  });

  //Adding the delete button 'X'
  let crossOutButton = $('<crossOutButton></crossOutButton>');
  crossOutButton.append(document.createTextNode('X'));
  li.append(crossOutButton);

  crossOutButton.on('click', deleteListItem);
  //Adding class delete (display: none) from css
  function deleteListItem() {
    li.addClass('delete');
  }

  //reordering the items
  $('#list').sortable();

}
ol li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
  cursor: move;
}

.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

crossOutButton {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form name="toDoList" onsubmit="newItem(); return false">
  <input type="text" name="listItem" id="input">
  <button id="button">Add</button>
</form>


<br/>
<ol id="list"></ol>




Thank you! So much simpler this way. I got tunnel vision once I got it to almost work and couldn't see any other fix. What does return false actually do for the onsubmit?

while using inline javascript is not recommended, it works and cancels the actual submit of the form
